PayPal NVP CURL connection error #28: Connection timed out after 60001 milliseconds
I configured the Paypal payment method in magento 2.4.6, but when I checkout I get a timed out error, the credentials and the installation are fine. I already tried upgrading the curl version but it didn't work.
I don't get a response when i run the command curl -v https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/
Curl version: 7.81.0
Error:

Exception: PayPal NVP CURL connection error #28: Connection timed out
after 60001 milliseconds in
/var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php


Did you manage to fix this error?

I didn't solve it as such, but I changed to the Paypal productive environment and it worked correctly for me. I still haven't found the solution to the sanbox issue.
curl -v https://www.paypal.com/
